# Load HTML Header content from template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I am trying to modify an application so that all of the application php structure runs in separate php files on the server and has nothing to do with the views rendered on the browser.  Essentially trying to move more towards a MVC structure.  Currently, I have pre-built header and navigation files load into the page like:

```
<?php include 'tpl/header.html'; ?>

<body>

<?php include 'tpl/navigation.html'; ?>
```

I'd like to pull out the php includes so that I am not reliant on them, but I'd still like to use templates for handling this so I don't have to touch each page.  I know how to do this for the navigation template using jQuery load, but is it possible for the header template file?

Would handlebars.js be a solution, and if so how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why don't you want to 'rely' on php include? I don't think you'll ever find a server that doesn't support php and it's clearly the shortest way (that gets evaluated on the server side)

Comment: Hi Velimir,  I eventually want to convert the entire application to a Phonegap app - and from what I've read Phonegap doesn't support php within html pages.  So I'm trying to see if I can convert the web app to support Phonegap's requirements before building the mobile design/functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append html to your head tag with javascript.

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/header.php');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
```

Comment: I think part of the issue is that jQuery gets loaded "after" the call.  I could include the jQuery dependency within the page, but I would rather have the link reference as part of the template if the version changes.  I have been looking to see if there is a pure javascript solution but I can't see that javascript has an include function.